# one version number to unite them all

Tags: jenkins, deployment

I have multiple build jobs for a project. ie:

projectA is built with different parameters, for SIT, UAT, Staging and Prod DC1, Prod DC2

I use the build ID within the code for cache busting JS and CSS files.

However, there is a little problem here.

I have multiple build IDs for Prod DC1 and DC2.

for example:

```
DC1: apple.com/me.js?v=45
DC2: apple.com/me.js?v=78
```

I need one id to unite them all. so that my apple.js?v=blah wont be different in DC1 and DC2. I am also using CDN so this might become a bigger problem.

How can I do this on jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

If all Jobs are connected as Upstream/Downstream way, create a version label parameter in the first Job and pass this label as parameter to the next downstream job till the last Job.

You can use this as the Unique label from starting Job to last Job.

Use [Build Name Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) to set the build name with the unique label for all the Jobs. So that it will be easy to identify the which build belongs to which label.

To have a full visibility of the Jobs use [Delivery Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin)